On track event in webrtc shows invalid access error
After my peerconnection gets disconnected , when I reconnect, I am getting this error
https://ibb.co/v3mZ2XK
ChatComponent.tsx:264 Uncaught (in promise) InvalidAccessError: Failed to execute 'getStats' on 'RTCPeerConnection': There is no sender or receiver for the track.
  async function onTrack(event: RTCTrackEvent) {
    if (!event.track) return;
    statsIntervalId.current = setInterval(async () => {
      if (peerConnectionRef.current) {
        console.log(peerConnectionRef.current.connectionState);
        const stats = await peerConnectionRef.current.getStats(event.track);
        stats.forEach((report) => {
          if (report.type === "inbound-rtp" && report.kind === "video") {
            const videoStatusChanged =
              videoIsPlaying !==
              report.bytesReceived > lastBytesReceived.current;
            if (videoStatusChanged) {
              const isVideoPlaying =
                report.bytesReceived > lastBytesReceived.current;
              setvideoIsPlaying(isVideoPlaying);
              onVideoStatusChange(isVideoPlaying, event.streams[0]);
            }
            lastBytesReceived.current = report.bytesReceived;
          }
        });
      }
      return null;
    }, 500);
  }

This is how I disconnect the peerconnection
  function closePC() {
    if (peerConnectionRef.current) {
      peerConnectionRef.current.close();
      peerConnectionRef.current.removeEventListener(
        "icegatheringstatechange",
        handleIceGathertingStateChange,
        true
      );
      peerConnectionRef.current.removeEventListener(
        "icecandidate",
        handleIceCandidate,
        true
      );
      //on Ice candidate
      peerConnectionRef.current.removeEventListener(
        "iceconnectionstatechange",
        handleIceConnectionStateChange,
        true
      );
      //connection state changed
      peerConnectionRef.current.removeEventListener(
        "connectionstatechange",
        handleConnectionStateChange,
        true
      );
      //signaling state changed
      peerConnectionRef.current.removeEventListener(
        "signalingstatechange",
        handleSignalStateChange,
        true
      );
      //on track event
      peerConnectionRef.current.removeEventListener("track", onTrack, true);
      if (statsIntervalId.current) {
        clearInterval(statsIntervalId.current);
      }
      if (streamId.current) {
        streamId.current = null;
      }
      if (sessionId.current) {
        sessionId.current = null;
      }
      if (lastBytesReceived.current) {
        lastBytesReceived.current = 0;
      }
      if (videoRef.current) {
        videoRef.current = null;
      }
      setPeerStatus(null);
      setSignalStatus(null);
      seticeStatus(null);
      seticeGatheringState(null);
      peerConnectionRef.current = null;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  const stopAllStreams = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(`stop alls treams`);
    const videoElement = videoRef.current;
    if (videoElement && videoElement.srcObject) {
      console.log("VIDEO GOT SRC===");
      const mediaStream = videoElement.srcObject as MediaStream; // Type assertion
      mediaStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
        track.stop();
        const sender = peerConnectionRef.current
          ?.getSenders()
          .find((s) => s.track === track);
        if (sender) {
          console.log("REMOVING FROM SENDER...");
          peerConnectionRef.current?.removeTrack(sender); // Remove track from RTCPeerConnection
        }
        const receiver = peerConnectionRef.current?.getReceivers();
        console.log({ receiver });
      });
      videoElement.srcObject = null;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }, []);

Basically I remove all the event listeners , disconnect the peer connection and remove the video's srcobject Element
This onTrack works in the initial connection. However, when I try to reconnect back after the peerconnection gets disconnected then the error on the ontrack event appears.
Thank you
